# Regex to remove Entire String from sentence not substring

Tags: java, regex, scala

I am very new to regular expression. I want to replace string from sentence using regular expression in scala or java.

Ex.

> "I am new to scala and scalapark is differnt"

I want to remove "scala" string from this statement not "scalapark".

> "I am new to and scalapark is differnt"

How can I perform this using regex.

Thanks in advance

Comment: @ScaryWombat Yes similar to that..I am sure that Statement will not contains any special character. because I had remove it.So we don't need to think of special character.

Comment: As it was already written \b would solve your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try this

```
String s = "I am new to scala and scalapark is differnt";
s = s.replaceAll("\\bscala\\b", "");
```

**Explanation**

1. `\\b` means word **boundary**
2. `scala` just matches **scala**